# Como contar los dias entre dos fechas de diferentes meses tambien de querer separarlas por meses en SQLPL

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus

Tengo la siguiente tabla llamada vacaciones, donde se muestra el número de empleado junto con la fecha inicial y final de sus vacaciones:

```
   La fecha de inicio sea 15 diciembre del 2021 y finaliza 30 de enero del 2022 son 47 dias lo cual yo quiero separar eso dias a ser 17 dias del mes diciembre y 30 dias de enero que tuvo mi empleado de su dia de vacaciones
```

Lo que busco es visualizar la cantidad de días de vacaciones que tuvo cada empleado, pero separándolo por mes.

Por ejemplo, si quisiera visualizar las vacaciones del empleado 01, se debería desplegar lo siguiente:

```
    día           DIAS
15/12/2021   17
30/01/2021   30
```

SQUERY SOLAMENTE OBTENGO EL TOTAL DE DIAS ENTRE DOS FECHA

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN TRUNC(SYSDATE) BETWEEN TRUNC(FECHA_INICIO) AND TRUNC(FECHA_FIN) THEN 'SI' ELSE 'NO' END AUSENTE,
TO_CHAR(FECHA_INICIO,'YYYYMM') MES,
ID_ASUSENCIA,
FECHA_INICIO,
FECHA_FIN,
FECHA_FIN+1 FECHA_FIN_CAL,
USUARIO USUARIO_INGRESA,
USUARIO_AUSENte,
TIPO_AUSENCIA,
COMENTARIO,
(SELECT FECHA_FIN - FECHA_INICIO from dual) +1 AS Dias
FROM TBL_AUSENCIAS_USUARIOS
```